# Select * parent records that have their children meet some criteria

Tags: sql

Let's say we have `todos` table with fields `title`, `deadline` and `subtasks` table that have subtasks for each todo.

So each subtask has `content` and `todo_id` fields.

How to fetch all todos which have their subtasks's content met some criteria?

For example `content LIKE 'foo'`

Comment: tag database name and also add sample and expected data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution using a `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* 
FROM todos t INNER JOIN subtasks st ON t.id = st.todo_id 
WHERE st.content LIKE '%foo%'
```

... or using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM todos 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM subtasks 
    WHERE todos.id = subtasks.todo_id AND subtasks.content LIKE '%foo%'
)
```

... or using `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM todos 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT todo_id 
    FROM subtasks 
    WHERE content LIKE '%foo%'
)
```